# Assign public ip to every openvpn client

Tags: linux, openvpn, tunneling

I've configured OpenVPN server which will assign private IP to the requested OpenVPN client. But I want to assign different public IP from the pool to every client. What changes need to be done for that?

```
ifconfig 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0
server-bridge 172.16.0.1 255.255.255.0 172.16.0.2 172.16.0.254
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer. We can define public IP gateway and IP ranges as above in the OpenVPN server config file. The client will get the public IP if requested for the VPN. Also, we have to remove the Nat from the server if private IP were provided before. To work with the public IP, we only need to mention the route from the gateway to the physical interface of that OpenVPN server. After that, all the VPN client will get the public IP as defined on the server.